# Emacs DOOM does not show tabs although 'centaur-tabs' is enabled

Tags: doom, tabs

I'm currently using DOOM emacs.

I enabled 'centaur-tabs' in ~/.doom.d/init.el by using `(tabs +centaur-tabs)`.

Configures are:

```
(after! centaur-tabs
  :ensure t                                                                                                                                               
  :config                                                                                                                                                 
   (setq centaur-tabs-style "bar"                                                                                                                          
         centaur-tabs-set-bar 'over                                                                                                                        
         centaur-tabs-height 32                                                                                                                            
         centaur-tabs-set-icons t                                                                                                                          
         centaur-tabs-gray-out-icons 'buffer)                                                                                                              
   (centaur-tabs-headline-match)                                                                                                                           
   (centaur-tabs-mode t))
```

However, tabs do not appear over the window.

I already did `doctor` and `sync`, and the errors are not shown.

Is there a bug related to using `centaur-tabs`?

Comment: @phils It's 27.2

Comment: @phils It prints out `GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86 64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2021-11-22`. Thank you.

Comment: See ```~/.emacs.d/modules/ui/tabs/config.el``` - it is already configured there. Compare with your code.

Comment: AFAIK tabs ought to work on linux (I believe they don't in Emacs 27 on MacOS, which was the main reason I was interested in the full version string).  I'm thinking of `tab-bar-mode` and `tab-line-mode` though -- does `centaur-tabs` just build off those, or is it something entirely different?  If the former, do tabs work if you run `emacs -Q` and enable `tab-bar-mode` and `tab-line-mode`?

Comment: @phils enabling `tab-bar-mode` and `tab-line-mode` make tabs to appear. However, it seems that these tabs are different from centaur-tabs.

Comment: Ok.  Well, I don't know what the problem is with centaur, but if you can't figure it out (or perhaps regardless) those standard tab modes might serve you better.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem, adding this line to `config.el` fixed issue for me (taken from [here](https://github.com/ema2159/centaur-tabs/issues/181#issuecomment-1075806796)):

```
(after! centaur-tabs (centaur-tabs-group-by-projectile-project))
```

It seems to be a bug of centaur tabs, line above is just a temporary workaround, not a solution. See [an issue](https://github.com/ema2159/centaur-tabs/issues/181).